# Why am I getting a warning in my browser console about "websiteroot", which is running continuosly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser-console

I am running a React app. Everything is perfect but  I am getting a warning in my browser console, like `***websiteRoot***` in content.js file

and this is running continuously, like the number in front of this warning is increasing per second.

I was expecting a clean console as there is no error in my code.

Comment: The developer tools logs UI should show where the source of the "websiteRoot" log is coming from, via the link on the right side of the log on most browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Unusual or continuous activities related to "websiteroot" could be a sign of a security breach. Ensure that your website and server are secure and have not been compromised.